# Angular: how to get a template ng-model into a directive for filtering

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create a directive which displays the template below and will ultimately allow for easy filtering.  When an option on the select list is selected and a value entered into the input box the model will change.  I need the directive to contain this model and then use the model for filtering.

[This](http://plnkr.co/edit/FrhQs8OrpUrBbgvylPpy?p=preview) is as far as I've got so far.  Can anyone give me some guidance on this as I'm pretty sure there's redundant code in my example too.

```
<div ng-controller="resultsCtrl">
    <div ng-controller="searchFilterCtrl">
  <dynamic-filters dynamic-filters-directive-search="getSearchFilters"></dynamic-filters>
</div>
<div ng-repeat="person in persons | filter: search">
  {{person.name}}
</div>
```

template:

```
<select ng-model="filterType">
    <option value="age">Age</option>
    <option value="customerId">CustomerID</option>
    <option value="productId">ProductID</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="select-option-value" ng-model="search[filterType]">
<p>You want to filter the field : {{filterType}}</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are close but it's actually simpler. Try [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/RKfLwVDlK8VDG2Vr3vSy?p=preview)

index HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="resultsCtrl">
  <dynamic-filters search="search"></dynamic-filters>
  <div ng-repeat="person in persons | filter: search">
    {{person.name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

directive HTML:

```
<select ng-model="filterType">
    <option value="age">Age</option>
    <option value="customerId">CustomerID</option>
    <option value="productId">ProductID</option>
    <option value="name">Name</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="select-option-value" ng-model="search[filterType]">
<p>You want to filter the field : {{filterType}}</p>
```

script.js JS code:

```
    angular.module('app', ['dynamicFiltersDirective']).controller('resultsCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.persons = [{
      name: 'Jim',
        age: 18,
      customerId: 1,
      productId: 4
  },{
      name: 'Frank',
        age: 20,
      customerId: 2,
      productId: 5
  },{
      name: 'Bob',
        age: 20,
      customerId: 3,
      productId: 5
  }];
});
```

directive JS code:

```
angular.module('dynamicFiltersDirective', [])
  .directive('dynamicFilters', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      scope: {
        search: '='
      },
      link: function(scope) {
        scope.$watch('filterType', function(v) {
          if(!v) {return;}
          //clear out the search
          scope.search = {};
          scope.search[v] = '';
        });
      },
      templateUrl: 'filtertemplate.html'
    }
  });
```

Comment: I was just doing something similar passing in search as an attr with a 2 way bind scope with this example:  http://plnkr.co/edit/3sXPZmhkOJd5uhMJkICx?p=preview

Thank you for your help :)